# Regex (grep) matching words made of exactly these letters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to grep a list of words and match those that have exactly some letters, no matter the order, but does matter the cuantity, for example, given these letters:

```
{ a, a, r, f, y, h, l }
```

over the list

```
hello
far
hala
miss
cam
```

should return

```
far
hala
```

I don't know if this can be done with regexes or must script something, any aproach is welcome.

Comment: Character classes. This is so totally googleable.

Comment: Would "halalala" match, or is it exactly 2 `a`s?

Comment: @Mathletics, as the title says, its exactly 2 'a's. I googled around for tree days and couldnt find the answer to this, maybe using "negative look aheads" (I don't really know what that is) does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the quantity restrictions using negative look aheads, one for each letter, and word boundaries either end of a simple character class

```
\b(?!([^a\W]*a){3})(?!([^r\W]*r){2})(?!([^f\W]*f){2})(?!([^y\W]*y){2})(?!([^h\W]*h){2})(?!([^l\W]*)l{2})[arfyhl]+\b
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/LCzywDzS3j), including matching words within longer lines.

The use of `\W` stops the look ahead running off the end of the word.

Comment: +1 If OP is looking for the permutation and combination without repeating any letter.

Comment: @Braj just to be clear, a single repetition of `a` is allowed - notice the different quantity for `a` (ie not 3). The other letters - yes, one max each

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do! Thanks a lot @Bohemian. Now I've got to lern more about it to fully understand.

Comment: No problem. Check out [this site](http://regular-expressions.com/reference.html) - it's a great place to learn from. Soon you can be impressing your friends and colleagues with regex Kung Fu

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as Bohemian, just a bit shorter due to the use of back references:

```
\b(?!\w*([rfyhl])\w*\1|\w*([a])(?:\w*\2){2})[arfyhl]+\b
```

Fiddle: http://regex101.com/r/gO6dC4/1

Answer (score 0):

Alphabetically sort the characters in each word; then you can use a straightforward regex `/^a?a?f?h?l?r?y?$/` (make sure the letters in the regex are in alphabetical order).

This AWK script will filter the words on stdin (one word per line):

```
awk 'function sort(s,z){l=split(s,a,"");asort(a);while(l)z=a[l--]z;return z;}sort($0)~/^a?a?f?h?l?r?y?$/'
```